# pygbag not working properly (not loading) when i add music

Tags: python, pygame, pygbag

i am using the pygabag lybrary to make python run on the web browser it works but when i  add some music it just shows a pitch black screen after pygbag's loading screen. when i remove music it works perfectly in the web browser, i am using pygbag' .ogg file format they automatically make. but it still does not load but if i remove only the music and my other sound it runs perfectly. when accessing the game from web browser

i get this error in the terminal

```
self.path='/songy-pygbag.ogg' path='/home/memo/jumpy_santa/build/web/songy-pygbag.ogg'
ERROR 404: https://pygame-web.github.io/songy-pygbag.ogg
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2023 09:26:49] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2023 09:26:49] "GET /songy-pygbag.ogg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

it says file not found?

but the file is in the directory

I use the music and the sound normally starting and running it when i want in my code using pygame's sound library called mixer.
It runs perfectly fine not in the browser with the music with both formats (i tried .mp3 and .ogg)but in the browser it does not load and gives me that error in the terminal with both formats.

here is how i load music

```
music = pg.mixer.music.load("songy-pygbag.ogg")
lost_sound = pg.mixer.Sound("lost_sound_effect-pygbag.ogg")
```

here is the entire code:

```
import pygame as pg
import asyncio
from constants import *
from bouncer import BouncePlatform
from player import Player
from buttons import button
from pygame import mixer

pg.init()
pg.mixer.init() 
mixer.music.set_volume(0.1)
music = pg.mixer.music.load("songy-pygbag.ogg")
lost_sound = pg.mixer.Sound("lost_sound_effect-pygbag.ogg")
pg.mixer.music.play(-1)
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption("Santa Jump")
clock = pg.time.Clock()

all_group = pg.sprite.Group()
platform_group = pg.sprite.Group()
for i in range(WIN_HEIGHT // 100):
    platform_spawn = i * 100
    BouncePlatform([platform_group, all_group], platform_spawn)
    
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

font = pg.font.Font("yoster_island123.ttf", 30)
font_bigass = pg.font.Font("yoster_island123.ttf", 60)

text_instruction1 = font.render('press space to start', True, (0,255,0))
text_instruction2 = font.render('press A and D to move', True, (0,255,0))

text_instruction1_rect = text_instruction1.get_rect()
text_instruction2_rect = text_instruction2.get_rect()

text_instruction1_rect.center = (WIN_WIDTH // 2, WIN_HEIGHT // 2)
text_instruction2_rect.center = (WIN_WIDTH // 2, WIN_HEIGHT // 2 + 25)

player = Player(all_group)
again = button(WIN_WIDTH //2 - 75, WIN_HEIGHT // 2, 'Play Again?', font, white)

def reset_game():
    player.reset()  # Add a reset method in your Player class to reset its position and state
    for plat in platform_group:
        plat.reset()  # Add a reset method in your BouncePlatform class to reset its position and state
    # Add any other game state variables that need to be reset

    # Reset flags and variables
    game_over = False
    pg.mixer.music.play(-1)  # Restart the background music


async def main():
    run = True
    game_over = False
    played_lost_sound = False
    instructions = True
    menu = False
    while run:
        if game_over != True:
            mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
        dt = clock.tick() / 100
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        for ev in pg.event.get():
            if ev.type == pg.QUIT or (ev.type == pg.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
                run = False
                
            if ev.type == pg.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                instructions = False
            
        if player.dead():
            game_over = True
            
        if menu != True:
            screen.fill((50, 10, 120))
            for plat in platform_group:
                print(game_over)
                plat.move(dt)
                plat.draw(screen)
                if plat.rect.colliderect(player.rect) and not player.up:
                    if player.rect.bottom < plat.rect.bottom:
                        player.bounce()
                    
            if instructions:
                screen.blit(text_instruction1, text_instruction1_rect)
                screen.blit(text_instruction2, text_instruction2_rect)

            if player.pos.y < WIN_HEIGHT / 2:
                y_offset = player.pos.y - WIN_HEIGHT / 2
                for sprites in all_group:
                    sprites.pos.y -= y_offset
                    
            if game_over == True: 
                pg.mixer.music.stop()
                reset_game()
                if played_lost_sound == False:
                    lost_sound.play()
                    played_lost_sound = True
                screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
                if again.draw_button(screen):
                    game_over = False
                    played_lost_sound = False
                text = font.render('you lost', True, (0,255,0))
                textRect = text.get_rect()
                textRect.center = (WIN_WIDTH // 2, WIN_HEIGHT // 2 - ((WIN_HEIGHT // 2) // 2))
                screen.blit(text, textRect)

            player.move(dt, keys)
            player.get_direction()
            if game_over == False:
                player.draw(screen)

        pg.display.update()
        
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
    pg.quit()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run( main() )
```

as i said i tried changing the file formats, but nothing worked.

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

firstly use .mp3 format then pygbag should make .ogg files automatically you will find them in your directory then remove the '-pygbag' from the filename with the .ogg format and that should solve it.